# Capture the URI, resource name,as seen in Developer Tools, from GET POST request method in Java

Tags: java, http, selenium

I am doing this as part of enhancing a Selenium Webdriver script. 
I have tried using httpclient with Java and a lot of other things but I am not able to get anywhere.
Please help!

Ths is the scenario:

After a certain action is performed in a webpage like a button click,
GET/POST methods can be seen in the Developer Tools in Chrome.

I have taken the example of Google here.

What I need here is to collect all the resource names until a certain resource appears (If you open the developer tools in Chrome and navigate to google.com , under the Network tab on the leftmost column you will see tia.png , just an example).

There are two things that should be achieved:

1. ensure that a certain resource was loaded
2. make sure the page is completely loaded (all GET / POST methods have been transferred) before any other action is taken.

The httpclient, httpurlconnection only capture one request, but a page sends a lot of requests. How do we capture all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer to my question :

https://kenneth.io/blog/2014/12/28/taking-chrome-devtools-outside-the-browser/
https://github.com/auchenberg/chrome-devtools-app

From the blog :

> It’s a standalone app that runs Chrome DevTools in its own process.
>   It’s powered by node-webkit, and it’s able to run on Windows, Mac and
>   Linux, completely independently of Chrome.

[image: The GET,POST,resource names seen under the Network tab in Chrome Dev tool]
I wanted to capture all the requests (as seen in the screenshot) between the application and the server so that I could ensure all the critical resources, requests have been transferred to and fro and a page has been completely loaded. 
I was unable to do this, perform programmatically what we see in the Chrome Dev tool under the Network tab in the image here.

Kenneth's work let's one achieve this to a degree.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

By Using http apache client , you can use something like this :-
To solve your problem, you can get the response code "response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()" and check for the expected response code and can also play with the outcome of the response.

```
URI url = new URI("String URI");
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
HttpResponse response = HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(post);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
System.out.println("Ressponse 1 >>>>"+result.toString());
```

And , if you need to send parameters in your post request like :-

```
List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "yourusername"));
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "yourPassword"));
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
```

Comment: Thank you Anil for trying to answer the question and not blindly voting down the question.

Comment: What Anil has mentioned here, I have already tried that. It doesn't do what the scenario needs.It gives me the html of the page which is not what i'm looking for. I can capture the response code with httpclient. But what i really need is to get the REQUEST-URI. I tried using httpservlet for the REQUEST method, but one needs to add it before deploying the application. And that's not what happens when you are testing an application that has been handed over to you.